# Is it possible make each story to have its own css in storybook?

Tags: styling, storybook

As I know, storybook will build one single "ALL IN ONE" css file and includes it in the html. Is it possible make each story to have its own css only? Like the picture below, each section can have the corresponding css resource.

[image]